# Can't figure out CSS layering

Tags: css

Looking at the image below, I have two main divs represented by the red and black outer div.
The black is visible by default and when you hover over one of the smaller black divs, the red div for that hovered box is displayed.
This works find on the first line, but if you look at the last box on the second line, you can see what I want to happen.
In reality all the red boxes on the second line are placed where the green line is. This is because of the height of the 3rd red box on the first line.
I've spend so much time trying to figure this out. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

```
<div class="container" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="red" style="position:relative;visibilty:visible;z-index:1">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="black" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;z-index:2">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would use Javascript to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position the red and black divs inside of a div.box with position: relative. Give the div.red boxes position: absolute and opacity of 0. Then add a rule to set opacity of the div.black to 0 and div.red to 1  on div.box:hover. See the example below. Notice that I made the red boxes larger than the black boxes but the flow is fine because position:absolute removes the red boxes from the document flow.

```css
div.box{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
}

div.box .red {
  opacity:0.0;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

div.box .black {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.box:hover .black {
  opacity:0;
}

div.box:hover .red {
  opacity:1.0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="position:relative;">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```